# How to get values from templatefields in Grdiview SelectedIndexChanged

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridview and sqldatasource.

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow row = GridView1.SelectedRow;
        TextBox rrdp = (TextBox)row.FindControl("name");
        txt1.Text = rrdp.text.ToString()
    }
```

But I'm getting : Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at the txt1.text = //etc..

The columns are itemtemplates , the values are not nulls.

Thanks

Comment: Posting more meaningful code would be helpful. Where is the code for your GridView

Comment: COde for the gridview wich one? :-? that's the code I'm trying to make wor

Answer (score 1):

It basically means that FindControl cannot find the control called "name" as per this line:

```
(TextBox)row.FindControl("name");
```

Have you checked if "name" is within any containers and is within the expected scope?  As the [FindControl docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h.aspx) specify it will return:

> The specified control, or null if the specified control does not
>   exist.

which is what you are experiencing (Object reference not set).

Comment: Hmm I used the code you gave , and it can't find the control. I don't know what do you mean by within any containers

Comment: what he means is: are you sure that inside your gridview, there is a textbox with "name" as it's ID ?

Comment: provide the HTML code of your GridView. That would be better.